# How to create private keys?

Tags: cleos

I created a collection of wallets for a private EOS testnet and I can generate passwords for the wallets. For the private key, there seems to be just one given in the [docs](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/wallets):

> 5KQwrPbwdL6PhXujxW37FSSQZ1JiwsST4cqQzDeyXtP79zkvFD3

How can we generate a series of private keys for all the different wallets? When I used

```
cleos wallet create_key
```

it just shows a new public key but I cannot see the private key eg

> Created new private key with a public key of:
>   "EOS6Pzm1Gs1eH3AxEQvZZdX2a71zASiwJdUn93775a92cbqcJR7ZJ"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Command: `cleos create key --to-console`

Link to command: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/v1.5.0/reference#cleos-create-key

---

From there you would do: `cleos wallet import [OPTIONS]`

```
Options:
  -n,--name TEXT              The name of the wallet to import key into
  --private-key TEXT          Private key in WIF format to import
```

Link to command: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/v1.5.0/reference#cleos-wallet-import

Comment: Brilliant - that worked.